# How can I choose a Config based on a server variable in Flask?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I am running nginx + gunicorn + flask

My nginx config looks like:

```
...

        proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header            Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header            Stage "development";

        proxy_redirect off;

...
```

My flask app looks like:

```
from flask import Flask, request

from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix

app = Flask(__name__)

# configuration settings

if request.headers.get('Stage') == 'production':
    app.config.from_object('config.production_config')
else:
    app.config.from_object('config.development_config')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "hello"

app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
```

However,

That doesn't seem to work.

I get a: RuntimeError: working outside of request context

My nginx is setup so that I can have a development/production environment, but I want to be able to say that this "server location" is a development environment, and I want Flask to use the appropriate configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The application config is for the whole application, while request headers are for just one request. The same application generally handles many requests. Therefore you can not set the config based on request headers.

Your code at the module level is executed at server start-up when no request as reached the application yet, so there is no current request. This is what the "working outside of request context" message means.

What you’re trying to do (prod vs. dev config) is better done with an environment variable in the script starting your gunicorn server. If you want both at the same time the easiest is to run two gunicorn servers.

Alternatively, make two application objects, run them both in the same process, and dispatch with a WSGI middleware similar to these: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appdispatch/

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old but I wanted to add how we accomplish this with flask. The majority of this is adapted from http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/ .

In our config.py we define multiple classes (one per environment):

```
class Config(object):
    FOO = 1
    BAR = 2

class Development(Config):
    BAR = 3
```

Then in each of our application nodes we set an environment variable in the gunicorn init scripts (for us this lives within a supervisor config but it doesn't have to be).

```
APPLICATION_ENV='Development'
```

Then within the flask application during initialization (only runs on server start, not within the request context):

```
try:
    env = os.environ['APPLICATION_ENV']
except KeyError as e:
    logging.error('Unknown environment key, defaulting to Development')
    env = 'Development'
    app.config.from_object('config.%s' % env)
```

now app.config['BAR'] will be 3.

We also wanted support for local config files (eg on a developer machine or passwords that are deployed from chef directly to the machine and not stored in git). To do that we've expanded on the above to also load a local config based on the app.config['LOCAL_CONFIG'] parameter.

```
class Development(Config):
    BAR = 3
    LOCAL_CONFIG = '/etc/localConfig.py'
```

And then in /etc/localConfig.py

```
BAR = 4
```

And again in our app initialization code after the code above loads the initial app.config for the environment:

```
if 'LOCAL_CONFIG' in app.config:
    #try to load the local configuration overrides
    if app.config.from_pyfile(app.config['LOCAL_CONFIG'], silent=True):
        logging.info('Loaded local config file at %s' % app.config['LOCAL_CONFIG'])
    else:
        logging.warning('Failed to load local config file at %s - does it exist?' % app.config['LOCAL_CONFIG'])
```

At this point app.config['BAR'] is 4.

This isn't perfect because if you have dicts in your config you will only be able to override the entire dict, not keys within it. It does accomplish most of what we need though.